# Where are the Freemarker Hibernate classes referenced located

Tags: hibernate, templates, reverse-engineering, freemarker

I am attempting to make custom reverse engineering templates for Hibernate.  In many of the templates I see online, I see variables such as pojo, class, c2j.  My question is where are these variable coming from ?  I can tell that the oft-mentioned pojo is a BasicPOJOClass entity but I can't seem to be able to find all of the variables available to a template.

For example, here is a ftl found on the web from some version of [hibernatetools](http://code.google.com/p/wsria/source/browse/branches/wsria-demo-sso/bin/hibernate/hibernatetools/pojo/Ejb3TypeDeclaration.ftl?r=44).

```
<#if ejb3>
<#if pojo.hasIdentifierProperty()>
<#if property.equals(clazz.identifierProperty)>
${pojo.generateAnnIdGenerator()}
<#-- if this is the id property (getter)-->
<#-- explicitly set the column name for this property-->
</#if>
</#if>
<#if c2h.isManyToOne(property)>
<#--TODO support @OneToOne true and false-->    
${pojo.generateManyToOneAnnotation(property)}
<#--TODO support optional and targetEntity-->    
${pojo.generateJoinColumnsAnnotation(property, cfg)}
<#elseif c2h.isCollection(property)>
${pojo.generateCollectionAnnotation(property, cfg)}
 <#else>
${pojo.generateBasicAnnotation(property)}
${pojo.generateAnnColumnAnnotation(property)}
</#if>
</#if>
```

Just by reading the template, you know there are variables available to you such as cfg, clazz, c2h and ejb3 but you have no idea of what they are and what methods on them are available to you.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most of the FreeMarker root context setup is handled in the [AbstractExporter](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools/blob/master/src/java/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/AbstractExporter.java) and [GenericExporter](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools/blob/master/src/java/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/GenericExporter.java) classes. It looks like there are a couple of variables available, e.g.

- artifacts
- c2h
- c2j
- cfg
- clazz
- exporter
- outputdir
- pojo
- template_path

If everything else fails you'll have to dig through those source files in order to find out about their meanings...

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Commander Chaquotay.  I have found alot of the variables I needed , it does appear that I am going to have to do ALOT of digging on this subject matter.